# DynamoDB & boto3: adding an index on nested values

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm required to create a small data store for clients to hold various service keys, which I'm trying to build using DynamoDB. For a given key, I'd like to know which client it belongs to.

The basic schema I'm aiming for is:

```
Client = {
    id: ...,
    keys: [
        {
            uuid: ...,
            type: ...,
            created: ...,
            expires: ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a `boto3` example that shows an index on an attribute inside a range (`key.created`).

As an alternative, I've considered breaking it up into two tables:

```
Client = {
    id: ...
}

Key = {
    uuid: ...,
    type: ...,
    created: ...,
    expires: ...,
    client_id: ...
}
```

This would require manually maintaining the relationships, though.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to create an index on `keys.created` in the first schema?
2. If it is, would the separate tables be a better approach, esp. if the `Key` table is denormalised to hold the client info it needs on lookup?

Cheers!